# Spring boot - read long value from properties

Tags: spring, application.properties

I am trying to read a long value (I will need also a String) from `application.properties` file. How can I do this? The guides I found aren't so clear.

Comment: Please, ad a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can help you out.

Comment: Add more details like  how you are calling ? what is the value of property?

Comment: Please check this answer once https://stackoverflow.com/a/42735568/1038268

Answer (score 0):

I Faced the same query and "\" saved me there.

suppose you need add Value : ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

you can write it like :

ABCDEF\
GHIJKL\
MNOPQR\
STUVWX\
YZ