# Spring @Value always gives an error if property is Integer

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am using sprin version 4.3.8.RELEASE. also i am using `@Value` to inject values from property file, if the properties are string that no problem, but if the property is `Integer` that is a problem (i know there is many questions about this i tried all the answers but the issue still exist)

The property is

```
CONNECTION.TIME.OUT=100000
```

**First solution**

```
@Value("${CONNECTION.TIME.OUT}")
protected Integer connectionTimeOut;
```

**Ecxeption**

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${CONNECTION.TIME.OUT}"
```

**Second solution**

```
@Value("#{new Integer('${CONNECTION.TIME.OUT}')}")
protected Integer connectionTimeOut;
```

**Exception**

```
EL1003E: A problem occurred whilst attempting to construct an object of type 'Integer' using arguments '(java.lang.String)'
```

**Third solution**

```
@Value("#{new Integer.parseInteger('${CONNECTION.TIME.OUT}')}")
protected Integer connectionTimeOut;
```

**Exception**

```
EL1003E: A problem occurred whilst attempting to construct an object of type 'Integer' using arguments '(java.lang.String)'
```

any ideas why is that

Comment: maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27106055/value-failed-to-convert-value-of-type-java-lang-string-to-required-type-j/27106543?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: While not a perfect solution, you could always get the property in a String variable and then parse it in an Integer. A simple way to do that would be to use the @Value annotation in a constructor argument and directly parse it into an integer variable in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `@Value("${CONNECTION.TIME.OUT}")` your error is `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${CONNECTION.TIME.OUT}"`. This means that expression was not processed resulting in `Integer.parseInt("${CONNECTION.TIME.OUT}")` which thrown the `NumberFormatException`.

Either there is no `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean registered in the Spring context and `@Value` annotations are not processed or there is no property `CONNECTION.TIME.OUT` defined.

Answer (score 8):

To avoid such type of situation where the exception occurs due to un-availibilty of the property, Add default value in the tag. If property is not available then it will populate the default value

```
@Value("${CONNECTION.TIME.OUT:10}")
```

Answer (score 4):

Your property file is probably not loaded properly.

When provided with no valid value for a property placeholder, Spring will automatically try to assign this value to the name of the `@Value` annotation. In your case, this:

```
@Value("#{new Integer('${CONNECTION.TIME.OUT}')}")
protected Integer connectionTimeOut;
```

Is interpreted as:

```
protected Integer connectionTimeOut = new Integer("${CONNECTION.TIME.OUT}");
```

Which, indeed, brings an error.

---

Try to either configure a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` in your beans, or make sure that your property file is loaded properly in your classpath by your configuration. Something among the lines of:

```
<context:property-placeholder
    ignore-unresolvable="true" 
    location="classpath:yourfile.properties" />
```

In your configuration file will help, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing single quotes worked ''. It worked for me.

```
@Value("#{new Integer(${CONNECTION.TIME.OUT})}")
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget the "${}" around it!  I kept looking at what should have been obvious and missing it.